# How to MATCH Dates in separate Columns and then SUM all values for a specific Date? (Google Sheets)

Tags: date, google-sheets, range, match, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a stock portfolio tracker.

Table 1 has all transactions in this format: Date | *Irrelevant* | Amount Bought (+) or Sold (-).

Table 2 has all Dates for every Day from the Date of the first purchase until the current Date.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMR8Q.png) [Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYwHe.png)

I am trying to get a Formula that calculates the total amount of shares bought/sold on a given day. Table 2 should then look like this:

[Goal (A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e92RD.png) [Goal (B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgSXf.png) [Goal (C)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV2eV.png)

I have tried some array formulas but cant figure out how SUM all Amounts for a specific Date.

This is what I currently have:

=ArrayFormula(INDEX(Transactions!$B$12:D, MATCH (TRUE,EXACT(Transactions!$B$12:B, B7),0)))

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this isn't really a proper question for stackoverflow, but try `=SUMIF(Transactions!$B$12:$B, B25, Transactions!$D$12:$D)' and just drag it down (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).